# How to call HTML button without ID or Name using VBA?

Tags: html, vba

I am not able to search for a solution for this in google. Maybe some will help me here.
Here is the HTML code for the combo box, I need to choose *Application Acknowledgement*

```
<select class=”form-control” data-bind=”options: UniqueCorrespondenceTemplates,value: SelectedLetter, optionsCaption:’-- select -- ‘”>
                <option value=””>-- select --</option>
                <option value=”Application Acknowledgement”>Application Acknowledgement</option>
                <option value=”Pend”>Pend</option>
                <option value=”Withdraw”>Withdraw</option> </select>
```

after that, two buttons will appear, **Validate** and **Cancel**..
Here's the validate button

```
<button class=”btn btn-success” data-bind=”click:validation,
visible: $root.canShowValidate() && !$root.ShowConfirmation()”>Validate</button>
```

I tried looking for the classname, but I does not appear in the loop. Maybe I did wrong. the code I used is in the office. I also tried parent.exep, the javascript trigger, gives a error. I found at google that this is a knockout js, but I don't know what that means.

Can anyone help me call/trigger those dropdown menu and button?

Comment: Try `getElementsByClassName("btn btn-success")(0).value = "Application Acknowledgement"` or you can iterate the `tagName` collection for the Button tag.

Comment: Those two codes are different. First one is the dropdown menu = Application acknowledgement. After choosing that, then the button appears. Validate and Cancel. Validate is the one above. Also the cancel button has the same class.

Comment: Use `getElementsByClassName("form-control")(0).value = "Application Acknowledgement"` The name in quotation marks  should be the name of the drop down control. For clicking the other control, something like this should work too. `getElementsByClassName("btn btn-success")(0).click` See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975198(v=vs.85).aspx